# Problem with GO and NEXT buttons on mobile keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, keyboard, multiplatform

In the code, I call a function that checks the text entered in the input field.
Everything works on the external keyboard. Unfortunately for the keyboard on the phone is not so easy. I assumed that each of the "input text" fields will be treated separately and after typing something in the middle just click GO (thereby sending information to the algorithms). However, these are treated as one large form and instead of GO the NEXT button is displayed, causing that instead of sending the value the focus moves to the next input text. Only the last one shows GO. Even worse, the values entered earlier into the previous input text are not sent. This effect causes that the website does not work for mobile devices.

[First Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcDza.jpg)

[Second Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zC01.jpg)

[Third photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DXLD.jpg)

[Link to webside with my game](http://talt-calc.ct8.pl/)

Like I said earlier on PC works fine. Try on mobile device too please.

I tried adding a  tag around each input text field to make the browser treat each field separately. I thought things would get better. Unfortunately, no. What's more, there was an error that caused the character names to be deleted. I've decided not to try to determine the cause of this absurd mistake for the time being. Or rather focus on finding some HTML tag or function in JS that would cause the input to be set to "final" or something like that. . .

Finally! After 2 weeks of searching the internet I found a solution!

here is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.%20com/questions/70867312/how-to-avoid-input-field-from-showing-next-option-instead-of-go-on-mobi#:%7E:text=%26lt%3Binput%20type%3D%26quot%3Btext%26quot%3B%20%2F%26gt%3B%20Will%20automatically%20%28on%20Android%29%20change,and%20it%20will%20jump%20to%20the%20next%20field.%20enterkeyhint%20attribute%20solved%20all%20my%20problems!).

enterkeyhint attribute solved all my problems!

```
<input enterkeyhint="next" />

change to:

<input enterkeyhint="go" />
```

Comment: I just want to add that the "Library" page is not ready yet so clicking on the link does not take you anywhere.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The whole code is public. It is placed on the website.